# Can I say "As I was given money, there are many ways to make use of them"?

Tags: grammar

My question is, can I say that? Does it make sense? Or, is that grammatically correct?

Comment: What do you intend *them* to refer to?

Comment: Them refers to money.

Answer (score 1):

Money is an **uncountable noun** which means it doesn't make sense to say something like "7 money". It also means you shouldn't refer to money as a plural like "them". You can refer to it as a singular, such as "it" though.

> Now that I have money, I'm looking for ways to spend it.

See also: [Money - Countable or Uncountable noun](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/87254/4194)